# ImageIO.write slow?

Tags: java, io

I've an application where I'm writing around 25 png image files to disk every second.

```
BufferedImage img = getBufferedImage();
// code below is very slow ~150ms.
File file = new File(count++ + ".png");
BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
ImageIO.write(img, "png", os);
```

It usually takes 150ms per call, and achieving 25fps hence becomes impossible. Can I buffer IO   so that I don't drop any frames?

Comment: Use some threading to do it in parallel

Comment: What have you measured? By that I mean is it the disk I/O that is slow, or is it the actual encoding process? If it's the disk I/O, then can you buffer *all* writes to memory first, and do the disk I/O on another thread? The usefulness of this idea depends on how quickly you need the written-to-disk image files available.

Comment: it runs on a single core machine, a new thread slows down the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PNG encoding takes a while and you can't improve it with any buffering ... if you want a speed up, use BMP (which will eat up your HDD) or if pixel-quality is not needed, try JPG (which should get encoded faster than PNG).

Comment: Do you really need the OutputStream? Have you tried to call `ImageIO.write(Image,String,File)`? ... might be that the output stream is causing a slow-down.

Comment: Both of them are equally slow

Comment: The fastest I have found is GIF + BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED