# Java ImageIO write is too slow

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am writing client-server app in Java, where client constantly takes screenshots and sends it to server using a socket. Server displays these images as they come, so it is kind of video streaming software.

My problem is that displayed video is not very smooth. I found out that it is due to conversion of BufferedImages to JPEG format using ImageIO ImageWriter write() method. I made a test class which tests performance of this conversion by taking 200 screenshots and then converting them:

```
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        new ConversionTest().test(200);
    }

    public static class ConversionTest {

        private BlockingQueue<byte[]> convertedImages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        private BlockingQueue<BufferedImage> screenshots = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        public void test(int numOfScreenshots) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Robot robot;
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Rectangle shotArea = new Rectangle(defaultToolkit.getScreenSize());
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfScreenshots; i++) {
                BufferedImage screenCapture = robot.createScreenCapture(shotArea);
                screenshots.add(screenCapture);
            }
            System.out.println(screenshots.size());
            
            
            ImageWriter writer =
                    ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
            long timeBefore = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfScreenshots; i++) {
                BufferedImage screenshot = screenshots.take();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                writer.setOutput(new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(bout));
                writer.write(new IIOImage(screenshot, null, null));
                bout.flush();
                convertedImages.add(bout.toByteArray());
            }
            long timeAfter = System.nanoTime();
            writer.dispose();
            double totalTime = (timeAfter - timeBefore) / 1000000.0 / 1000.0;
            System.out.println(numOfScreenshots + " screenshots: " + totalTime + " sec");
            System.out.println(numOfScreenshots / totalTime + " of screenshots per second.");
        }
    }
}
```

The output after running this code on my machine is:

```
200 screenshots: 11.331018700000001 sec
17.650663660099685 of screenshots per second.
```

Is it possible to increase performance of this tested code fragment? And if so, how can I achieve that? I would like to increase number of screenshots per second to about 30 or more.

Comment: 18 FPS for java is kind of good I think. If you need more performance, just forget java.

Comment: I see only a few way outs. 1) benchmark JPEG encoders (find a native one ?) 2) lower the image definition, 3) multithread and/or 4) 30 JPEG/sec is usually called a video, what not use a video encoder ?

Comment: There exists [another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973071/imageio-write-slow). So you can try it with GIF and BMP.

Comment: @flaxel GIF format is not good for my case because image quality is too low (not all colors are represented correctly), and BMP generates too much data to transfer over socket (about 6 MB for every screenshot on my PC, which would equal to 180 MB per second for 30 fps). It would move the performance issue from converting images to transfering them over the network. Out of these formats I think JPEG works best and I think I would like to increase performance of conversion using this format.

Comment: There are some minor things you could do, like putting `bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()`  outside the loop. You are currently creating a lot of garbage that may affect performance. Also, experiment with the JPEG quality. But I think your best bet is to use some kind of delta compression, and perhaps dynamic quality. Native code will probably be a bit faster, using modern hardware even faster.